# Why people use `rel="noopener noreferrer"` instead of just `rel="noreferrer"`

Tags: html, security

I often see following pattern:

```
<a href="<external>" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
```

But as far as I see, `noreferrer` implies the effect of `noopener`. So why is `noopener` even needed here?

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer

> `<a href="..." rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">` has the same behavior as `<a href="..." rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">`.

Note that `noreferrer` browser support is strictly wider that one of `noopener`
https://caniuse.com/#feat=rel-noreferrer
https://caniuse.com/#feat=rel-noopener

Comment: https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/  see this .

Answer (score 31):

> Tag rel with "noopener" and "noreferrer" combined means that no referrer information should be passed to the website being linked to because of noreferrer tag and also prevents the newly opened page from controlling the page that delivered the traffic.

`rel="noreferrer"` prevent the referrer header from being sent to the new page. `rel="noopener"` prevent the browser from open the page on the same process as the other page, preventing the linking page to be spoofed by evil JavaScript on the destination page. Before `rel="noopener"` a link could change the entire webpage where you clicked on a link, and the change would have been managed by the destination page. Modern browser are by default, adding the `rel="noopener"` on every link. Iphone X did that 2017 which you could see for a while by, in Iphone, going to Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Webkit Features"` and toggle that feature on and off. That option can not be done anymore, since it's default.

There is  no good reason to remove `rel="noopener"` since it doesn't seem to have any downside. It adds a process for the new page, instead of running the pages on the same process. For modern browsers the attribute value is just indicating what the browsers are already doing.

Comment: "makes sense to use both of them to support older browsers" – do you know any browsers that support `noopener` but not `noreferrer`?

"There is also no good reason to remove `rel="noopener"`" – are there any good reasons to include it?

"doesn't seem to have any downside" – one example of a minor downside is an increased file size.

"it is something widely considered" – I'm just curious what are the reasons behind this consideration.

Comment: Yes, good questions. I searched a lot before answering this. To be honest, I have the same doubts, and I don't know exactly why there is this general recommendation to use both. However, nothing in the answer is personal opinion, I just answered using statements I found in order to direct you to what is considered consensus, which seems to be just a convention as well. Also, I marked this question for myself as a reminder to keep searching further ahead. If I discover more objective information in the future, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you for you research. Speaking of older browsers support, I have actually found that in Firefox 33-35 `rel="noreferrer"` removes `window.opener` while `rel="noreferrer noopener"` doesn't: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2022#issuecomment-524631866

Comment: -1, This does not answer the question: "`noreferrer` implies the effect of `noopener`. So why is `noopener` even needed here?"

Answer (score 11):

Yes, `noreferrer` implies `noopener`, making the additional value redundant. And an old version of Firefox even requires that `noopener` be omitted when using `noreferrer`.

Using both probably became a habit after following outdated recommendations or lint rules.

See:

- [ESLint "noreferrer" discussion](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/2022)
- [WHATWG HTML spec - 4.6.7.14 Link type "noreferrer"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer)

Answer (score 1):

This note might be an addition to the discussion:

> Note: Setting target="_blank" on  elements now implicitly provides the same rel behavior as setting rel="noopener" which does not set window.opener.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/noopener)